# Creating a new table from existing table with a ">" constraint

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I got a table called "Tweets" and I need to create a new table called "New_Tweets" with the same attributes as the original "Tweets" table and I need to add a constraint in here. I tried using WHERE for the constraint, but I noticed that ">" is not possible in a WHERE statement. Then I tried using HAVING which also didn't work. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT *
INTO New_Tweets
FROM Tweets
WHERE created > AVG(created)
```

I'm using SQL in microsoft access (don't ask me why). I only have very basic knowledge of SQL so please don't be too harsh haha.

Comment: You may want to include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery.  The problem isn't `>`, it is the `AVG()`.  So:

```
SELECT *
INTO New_Tweets
FROM Tweets
WHERE created > (SELECT AVG(created) FROM Tweets);
```

That said, `created` usually refers to a date.  This only works if `created` is numeric.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed it

Comment: And yes the date was numeric